# Label not aligned correctly

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, text-alignment

I am using pydev on eclipse luna. My kv file is as follows:

```
<LoginForm>:
    userid: userid
    password: password

    size_hint_x: 0.5
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 200

    orientation: 'vertical'
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y':0.5}

    minimum_height: 100
    minimum_width: 100

    #User ID
    Label:
        text: 'User ID'
        font_size: 20
        size_hint_x: None

    TextInput:
        id: userid
        font_size: 20


    #User PW
    Label:
        text: 'Password'
        font_size: 20

    TextInput:
        id: password
        password: True
        font_size: 20

    Button:
        text: 'Login'
```

My python code is:

```
from kivy.app import App;
from forms.login import LoginForm;
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class LoginForm(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class StartApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (480, 800)
        return LoginForm()

        #return StartApp();

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StartApp().run()
```

Output:
[image]

The code is working correctly, however, my issue is that there is still some gap at left which is not present for other controls. I want User ID to be completely left aligned (in the above pic it is left aligned, but some space is still left).

Could you please advice/correct me on where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Label isn't left-aligned because you haven't actually set that, by disabling the size_hint_x it just takes the default width of 100 pixels and the text appears in its centre.

You have two options for declaring the label.

```
Label:
        text: 'User ID'
        font_size: 20
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.texture_size[0]
```

This will set the width of the Label to the exact size of the texture containing the image of the text. However, I think it's probably preferable to do the following:

```
Label:
        text: 'User ID'
        font_size: 20
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
```

This way, rather than messing with the widget size/position you set the text_size (this controls the bounding box of the text texture) and the built in text alignment options take care of the rest.

In this case, the results of these should be similar if not identical.